# Application with reentrantLock condition hangs on sometimes

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, thread-dump

I have following code snippet:

```
public class ConditionTest {

    public static final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static final Condition CONDITION_PRODUCED = reentrantLock.newCondition();
    public static final Condition CONDITION_RECEIVED = reentrantLock.newCondition();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread receiverThread = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                reentrantLock.lock();
                try {
                    CONDITION_PRODUCED.await();
                    System.out.println("Received");
                    CONDITION_RECEIVED.signal();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                reentrantLock.unlock();
            }
        });
        Thread senderThread = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                reentrantLock.lock();
                if (i != 0) {
                    try {
                        CONDITION_RECEIVED.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Produced");
                CONDITION_PRODUCED.signal();
                reentrantLock.unlock();

            }
        });
        receiverThread.setName("received");
        senderThread.setName("Producer");

        receiverThread.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        senderThread.start();
    }
}
```

sometimes it works correctly and I see expected output. But sometimes it works wrong and hangs after printing:

```
Produced
Received
```

thread dump:

```
2018-03-14 14:47:58
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode):

"JMX server connection timeout 18" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e149800 nid=0x16ac in Object.wait() [0x000000001fb1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076c76d070> (a [I)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
    - locked <0x000000076c76d070> (a [I)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e15d000 nid=0x2f3c waiting on condition [0x000000001fa1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000076c438500> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.56.1" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e3b8800 nid=0x1674 runnable [0x000000001f91e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x000000076c6f8d18> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:550)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$3/342486007.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x000000076c469b90> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e065800 nid=0x20e8 runnable [0x000000001f71f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x000000076c4402e8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DestroyJavaVM" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002d1b000 nid=0x2c54 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Producer" #12 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e3d3800 nid=0x24b0 waiting on condition [0x000000001ef1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000076b80c210> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at com.cryptex.fix.performance.ConditionTest.lambda$main$1(ConditionTest.java:32)
    at com.cryptex.fix.performance.ConditionTest$$Lambda$2/326549596.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"received" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e3d2000 nid=0x1a18 waiting on condition [0x000000001ee1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000076b80c1f8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at com.cryptex.fix.performance.ConditionTest.lambda$main$0(ConditionTest.java:18)
    at com.cryptex.fix.performance.ConditionTest$$Lambda$1/1642360923.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e050800 nid=0x2a10 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread2" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001df1d800 nid=0x2ea8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001df1d000 nid=0x136c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001df1c000 nid=0x2a98 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #6 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e023800 nid=0x2f58 runnable [0x000000001e81e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x000000076b91a460> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    - locked <0x000000076b91a460> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2$1.run(AppMainV2.java:64)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c4db800 nid=0x2f48 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c4da000 nid=0x10f8 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000001c4c0000 nid=0x228c in Object.wait() [0x000000001d82f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076b508e98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x000000076b508e98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000002e07000 nid=0x1204 in Object.wait() [0x000000001d72f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076b506b40> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x000000076b506b40> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c497800 nid=0x2784 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002d2e800 nid=0x848 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002d30800 nid=0x20cc runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002d32000 nid=0x1c5c runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002d33800 nid=0x20bc runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001e13d000 nid=0x2dc waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 350
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Can you mention what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

From *Java Concurrency in Practice*

> **Condition wait errors.** When waiting on a condition queue, Object.wait or Condition.await should be called in a loop, with the appropriate lock held,
>   after testing some state predicate (see Chapter 14). Calling Object.wait or
>   Condition.await without the lock held, not in a loop, or without testing
>   some state predicate is almost certainly an error.

Since you don't do this, you're likely experiencing a missed signal, or less likely but also possible, a spurious wakeup, which throws off the syncing between the two threads.

A possible correction would be

```
public class ConditionTest {

    public static final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static final Condition CONDITION_PRODUCED = reentrantLock.newCondition();
    public static final Condition CONDITION_RECEIVED = reentrantLock.newCondition();
    private static boolean state = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread receiverThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    reentrantLock.lock();
                    while (state) {
                        CONDITION_PRODUCED.await();
                    }

                    state = true;
                    System.out.println("Received");
                    CONDITION_RECEIVED.signal();
                    reentrantLock.unlock();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });

        Thread senderThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    reentrantLock.lock();
                    while (!state) {
                        CONDITION_RECEIVED.await();
                    }
                    state = false;

                    System.out.println("Produced");
                    CONDITION_PRODUCED.signal();
                    reentrantLock.unlock();

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        receiverThread.setName("received");
        senderThread.setName("Producer");

        receiverThread.start();
        senderThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when the producer thread generates a signal for the condition `CONDITION_RECEIVED` *before* the consumer thread has started to wait for signals on this condition (`CONDITION_PRODUCED.await()`). In this case, the signal is "lost" and both threads end up waiting for each other.

You may handle this situation with `boolean` flags shared by both thread, but I wouldn't advise it, as it would be error-prone, difficult to read and debug, and hard to extend because producers and consumers would be tightly coupled.

Usual producer/consumer patterns involve *queues*. They provide you with an easier to understand and more loosely-coupled and extensible design.

```
BlockingQueue<Integer> produced = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
BlockingQueue<Integer> requests = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

Thread receiverThread = new Thread(() -> {
    int i = 1;
    requests.offer(i);
    while (i < 10) {
        try {
            produced = queue.take();
            System.out.println("Received: " + i);
            requests.offer(i + 1);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Something which does not swallow the interruption
        }
    }
});

Thread senderThread = new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        try {
            int i = requests.take();
            System.out.println("Produced: " + i);
            produced.offer(i);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Something which does not swallow the interruption
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How would a boolean flag be error prone? This technique has been used for decades and not just with Java. P/C are already coupled.

Answer (score 0):

Never call `wait()/await()` without loop!

@bowmore's solution doesn't follow the typical order of producer/consumer pattern.

```
public class ConditionTest {

    public static final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static final Condition CONDITION_PRODUCED = reentrantLock.newCondition();
    public static final Condition CONDITION_RECEIVED = reentrantLock.newCondition();
    private static boolean dataAvailale = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread receiverThread = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                reentrantLock.lock();
                try {
                    while (!dataAvailale){
                        CONDITION_PRODUCED.await();
                    }

                    dataAvailale = false;
                    System.out.println("Received " + i);
                    CONDITION_RECEIVED.signal();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                reentrantLock.unlock();
            }
        });

        Thread senderThread = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                reentrantLock.lock();
                while (dataAvailale) {
                    try {
                        CONDITION_RECEIVED.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                dataAvailale = true;

                System.out.println("Produced " + i);
                CONDITION_PRODUCED.signal();
                reentrantLock.unlock();

            }
        });
        receiverThread.setName("received");
        senderThread.setName("Producer");

        receiverThread.start();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        senderThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Enlighten me, what is essentially the difference between your code and the one I have in my answer?

Comment: Nothing but  the order of execution of producer/consumer thread (OP's expectation: producer > consumer > producer > consumer and so on, but your output: consumer > producer > producer > consumer or something similar). However, I wanted to comment on your post instead of posting a separate answer, but I can't comment due to the lack of reputation. In fact, I've up-voted your answer. Having said that, if you think it's redundant I'm happy to delete it.

Comment: I have, meanwhile, slightly edited my answer (basically changed the state starting value) and then the expected order does come out. But as the two threads just play ping pong, and don't actually produce and consume data, only the System out betrays their roles. Another possible fix was to switch the output around :)